# Unable to get Google Drive's file or its metadata on my Webstore App

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-chrome-app, google-api-php-client

I want users to open a file using my *Chrome webstore app* and then I'll process the file and metadata I get. I have been following Google's official documentation and yet I am unable to achieve it.

I added the libraries from [Github's Google-api-php-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) and this is one of my codes I've been trying:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
// Get your credentials from the console
$client->setClientId('xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com');
$client->setClientSecret('xxxxx');
$client->setRedirectUri('https://my_site.com/path/driveapp.php');
$client->setScopes(array(
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
  'email',
  'profile'));
$client->setUseObjects(true);

// if there is an existing session, set the access token
if ($user = get_user()) {
  $client->setAccessToken($user->tokens);
}

// initialize the drive service with the client.
$service = new Google_DriveService($client);

/**
 * Gets the metadata and contents for the given file_id.
 */
$app->get('/svc', function() use ($app, $client, $service) {
  checkUserAuthentication($app);
  checkRequiredQueryParams($app, array('file_id'));
  $fileId = $app->request()->get('file_id');
  try {
    // Retrieve metadata for the file specified by $fileId.
    $file = $service->files->get($fileId);

    // Get the contents of the file.
    $request = new Google_HttpRequest($file->downloadUrl);
    $response = $client->getIo()->authenticatedRequest($request);
    $file->content = $response->getResponseBody();

    renderJson($app, $file);
  } catch (Exception $ex) {
    renderEx($app, $ex);
  }
});
```

I've been following all the steps that I am supposed to; went to console, configured the Drive SDK, enabled the Drive API, created Client ID, cared about the parameters in my json of my Chrome web-app. But I still keep getting syntactical errors after I use methods that are mentioned in the document.

From what I get, the documentation isn't updated, hence there are issues with paths of library's files.

PS: I've checked [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-php), [Authorize Requests](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/auth/web-server), and [examples](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/examples/php)' codes, but nothing helped.

Comment: What does PHP have to do with a Chrome App? Which documentation are you following?

Comment: Been following this: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/ And, my Chrome App sends file's state parameters after providing access to the app using OAuth 2.0. So, my app is just used to redirect user to my PHP site and there I will need the file and it's metadata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its tricky using the latest PHP library for drive api. There is a lack of documentation on the web too.
This code works for me, it should help you:

```
<?php

session_start();
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php';


$client_id = '';
$client_secret = '';
$redirect_uri = '';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive");
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

function printFile($service, $fileId) {
  try {
    $file = $service->files->get($fileId);

    print "Title: " . $file->getTitle();
    print "Description: " . $file->getDescription();
    print "MIME type: " . $file->getMimeType();
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
  }
}

if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
  unset($_SESSION['upload_token']);
}
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['upload_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

}
if (isset($_SESSION['upload_token']) && $_SESSION['upload_token']) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['upload_token']);
  if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    unset($_SESSION['upload_token']);
  }
} else {
  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
}

if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  // This is uploading a file directly, with no metadata associated.
  if (isset($_GET['state'])) {
    $a = urldecode(urldecode($_GET['state']));
    $state = json_decode(stripslashes($a));
    $_SESSION['mode'] = $state->action;

    if (isset($state->ids)){
      $_SESSION['fileIds'] = $state->ids;
    } else {
      $_SESSION['fileIds'] = array();
    }
    if (isset($state->parentId)) {
      $_SESSION['parentId'] = $state->parentId;
    } else {
      $_SESSION['parentId'] = null;
    }        
    $fileId = $_SESSION['fileIds'];
    printFile($service, $fileId[0]);
}



 }

?>
```